# Query multiple WMI objects in PowerShell and export to Excel

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to query multiple [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) objects and select required values from each object and export to Excel?

I want to achieve: Get the computer name and owner's name from the win32_computersystem class and serial number from the win32_bios class and export the results in a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) to get the complete inventory of the computer systems in my organization.

How can it be acheived?

Comment: Yes, this can be done and it's a fairly common scenario. How much research have you done into this, and what have you tried to achieve the goal? And why aren't you using an already-built tool like SCCM that's designed to inventory the systems on your network and can produce this report automatically for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom object with desired properties. Use [New-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx) to create one. Use [Add-Member](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx) to add `noteproperty` members to the object. Get data with WMI ([Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx) - alias `gwmi`) and populate object's properties with those.

Collect objects into an array and export it as CSV with [Export-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx).

Try it like so,

```
$computers = @("System1", "System2") # An array of computer names.
$arr = @() # Array for CSV export

foreach($comp in $computers){
  $o = new-object  psobject # New object

  # Add Owner property and set its value with a WMI call
  $o | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name Owner -value (gwmi win32_computersystem -computername $comp).PrimaryOwnerName

  # Ditto for Serial property
  $o  | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name Serial -value (gwmi win32_bios -computername $comp).SerialNumber

  $arr += $o
}

# Export the object data as CSV
$arr | select -property Owner,Serial | export-csv -notypeinformation c:\temp\ownerdata.csv
```